# share post on facebook using applinks iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

I am working on a app which has the user feed of posts and I want to post feed post on facebook just like instagram do and if user will clicks on facebook shared post user will redirect to app or appstore, we are not using any post hosting server.
To implement this feature I found [this url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios) from facebook and I successfully got the object:

```
{
  "canonical_url": "url",
  "id": "643402985734299"
}
```

here I am facing problem to share my post with this given object please help.

Comment: have you checked `Adding App Links to Your Existing Web Content`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a deferred deep linking service like [Branch](http://branch.io) which is free to use. You'll be able to generate links that work from [most other apps](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#expected-redirect-behavior) including Facebook. You can start by [implementing the iOS SDK](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/).

In terms of sharing, you should be able to use the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios) to add functionality for sharing pieces of content directly to Facebook. If you embed a Branch link as the `contentURL` you'll be able to link to the content in your app regardless of whether the app is installed.

Branch already leverages App Links for you so you do not need to do any specific handling just for Facebook.